# Infinite for loop in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

While I am reading in a code, I found that the loop for was used with just two arguments (the one in the middle is absent). When the program is executed, the loop for is infinite. Here is a minimal working environment. Could anyone tell what is wrong in the code?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; ; i = (i+1)%2)
  {
      cout << i << endl;
      }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong with the code?

Comment: I cannot figure out the usage of the loop for here. Thanks.

Comment: You mean what it's doing here? Or do you mean how to get it to do something else? Can you clarify what it is you don't understand. Do you know what each of the three statements does?

Comment: No, I have no idea at all. What I use generally is the classical syntax of the loop for. This syntax is new for me!

Comment: the internet is your friend [C++ for loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm)

Comment: Don't you need `std::endl` or `using namespace std;` to compile this code?

Comment: Indeed, we should add it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

when you have

```
for (statement 1;statement 2;statement 3){}
```

statement 1: performs at entry to the for loop

statement 2: is checked before every new iteration, if it evaluates as 0/false it doesn't continue

statement 3: is performed at end of every iteration regardless.

if you leave statement 2 empty it default to true/1 and so every time it loops it will evaluate as continuing and so will be an infinite loop

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with the code, it's doing exactly what you told it to do.

The second section of the `if` statement is the continuation condition which, if omitted, defaults to true.

In fact, you can leave out any combination of the loop initialisation, continuation condition and post-iteration sections and they will default to, respectively:

- no initialisation.
- continue forever (in the absence of control flow statements like `break`).
- no post-iteration actions.

which is why:

```
for (;;)
```

is a perfectly valid infinite loop.

Comment: "second stanza of the if statement" What does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

This is explained in the C standard. §6.8.5.3:

> 1 The statement
>
> for ( *clause-1* ; *expression-2* ; *expression-3* ) *statement*
>
> behaves as follows: The expression *expression-2* is the controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body. *[..]*
>
> 2 Both *clause-1* and *expression-3* can be omitted. An omitted
>   *expression-2* is replaced by **a nonzero constant.**

That essentially means that it will repeat forever.

A further explanation continues in a footnote (which is considered non-normative):

> 158) Thus, *clause-1* specifies initialization for the loop, possibly
>   declaring one or more variables for use in the loop; the controlling
>   expression, ***expression-2*, specifies an evaluation made before each
>   iteration, such that execution of the loop continues until the
>   expression compares equal to 0**; and *expression-3* specifies an
>   operation (such as incrementing) that is performed after each
>   iteration.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the code. This allows infinite counting (to an int's limit that is) until an internal condition stops it. None of the three parts of a for loop are necessary, thus any of the below are valid.

```
for(;;); // Yes, this will never stop

for(int x = 0;;){

}

for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x);

for(; someCondition != true;){}
```

And so on, all parts are optional, even the body.

A reason this might be used would be that if one thing is done with the data, I need to stop, but if another thing, I want to do something with it. However, at the same time, I need to know how many times it's happened. You'll use it without all the parameters eventually, but for now, just understand that to have a valid for loop, all you have to have is the top line in my code snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for a for loop in C++ is:

```
for ( init; condition; increment )
{
   //statement(s) to be executed while the condition is true
}
```

See here for more details: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm

Your prgram missed the condition statement. Therefore, the for loop repeated forever.